# How do you manage multiple services while developing locally?

Tags: python, service

We're building web applications in Python and it isn't rare to require 3 or more services to be running (search, db(s), task queues, web app, etc.) just to work on the project locally. Manually firing off each service in a new console (then remembering to restart it when you change the code) is slow and error prone.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to give developers on our projects a single command that will:

- start all the required services
- log any output to the console
- restart services automatically if the code changes (via something like [pywatch](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywatch/) or inotify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).  I used it when I was writing an app that combined nginx and tornado. It will handle starting and monitoring of the services you define, and give you an interface to control them as a group.

It doesn't have file monitoring built in, but there may be a plugin (update: there doesn't seem to be one), or you could send it event via a script to watch the files.

Comment: Didn't find a plugin, but [watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) works well. I added an additional supervisor program with a script like this: `watchmedo shell-command --patterns="*.py" --recursive --command='supervisorctl restart some_service' /path/to/some/service/`

Comment: @Pete - nice! I didn't know about the watchmedo script, but it looks like it would be perfect here.